# Bound degrees of sparse random graphs

Tags: probability, random-graphs, geometric-functional-analysis

I might be wrong but I think this problem (Exercise 2.4.2) means $d=o(\log n)$? If so, can anyone give a hint instead of telling the answer.

[image]
[image]